# Pull multiple columns when an alias is used

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull two columns from an SQL table, however I need to use one as an alias due to the DISTINCT(). I cannot find much in the docs for this situation, so I have turned here.

This works (without the second column):

```
SELECT distinct(message_recips.userid) as userid 
FROM message_recips WHERE messageid = ?
```

However this doesn't:

```
SELECT distinct(message_recips.userid) as userid, users.email 
FROM message_recips 
INNER JOIN users ON users.email = message_recips.userid 
WHERE messageid = ?
```

Why does adding the second column (users.email) cause this to not work? I am simply trying to get the email addresses of the users who are recipients of the messages. The first query gets the message recipients perfectly, and I am pretty confident that is the correct format to get the email addresses.

The query returns no results, but not an error.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You not just added a column you joined the second table as well. Describe how exactly the new code *doesn't work*? Does you query run? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Read and act on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your second (nonworking) query appears to be trying to join an email address to a user id number. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: thanks you guys. I was not thinking straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is asking for the userids and emails from all possible rows that can be made from a row from each table where also the users.email = message_recips.userid.

Since you get get no rows back, you have no user emails that are equal to a message_recips userid.

(Not surprising.)

You probably want:

```
SELECT distinct(message_recips.userid) as userid, users.email 
FROM message_recips 
INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = message_recips.userid 
WHERE messageid = ?
```

Comment: oh crap you are right. I know how to do this. jesh. Thanks for working with me.